# Django - bulk_create() lead to memory error

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have around 400 000 object instances to insert in postgres. I am using bulk_create() to do so, but I face a Memory error.

My first idea was to chunk the list of instances:

```
def chunks(l, n):
    n = max(1, n)
    return [l[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

for c in chunks(instances, 1000):
    Feature.objects.bulk_create(c)
```

But sometimes that strategy also leads to Memory Error because instance's size can vary a lot, so a chunk could exceed the memory limit while others dont.

Is it possible to chunk the list of instances in order to have chunks of delimited size? What would be the best approach in this case?

Comment: split your bulk in smaller ones or if it still leaks, fork before every bunch and perform inserts in child proc

Comment: How do you obtain instances ? Try using a generator (yield) to create instances.

Comment: You can check the memory on the fly. So your bulk sizes can differ based on the amount of memory they use. Cant give an example right now, mb later.

Comment: @BelowtheRadar is ``instances`` a generator or an iterator ?

Comment: @Serafeim its an iterator, i'll try your suggestion

Comment: Does celery could help in this issue? If yes, some explanations would be helpful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your are using Django in debug mode it will keep track on all your sql statements for debugging purposes. For many objects this may cause memory problems. You can reset that with:

```
from django import db
db.reset_queries()
```

see [why-is-django-leaking-memory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/faq/models/#why-is-django-leaking-memory)

Comment: Absolutely this. You really have to be careful about operating with `DEBUG=True` if you have a large number of queries and/or large datasets going over SQL. Even if it's not specifically what you're running into right *now*, you likely will bump into it if you aren't conscientious of it.

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day

Answer (score 12):

You can specify the batch_size in the bulk_create method.

```
Syntax: bulk_create(objs, batch_size=None)
Feature.objects.bulk_create(instances, batch_size=1000)
```

Django 2.2: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

Django 3.1: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

Comment: its true but I think the batch_size parameter is doing the same thing as my chunks() method

Answer (score 6):

If you are not running with DEBUG mode, and you still have errors, my solution should help you. First, ensure that you have a lazily generated set of objects to be saved (for example, fetched from remote API in batches)

```python
def generate_data():
    """Example data generator"""
    for i in range(100000):
        yield Model(counter=i)

data_gen = generate_data()
# >> print data_gen
# <generator object data at 0x7f057591c5c8>
# 
# it's a generator, objects are not yet created. 
# You can iterate it one-by-one or force generation using list(data_gen)
# But for our approach, we need generator version
```

Next, we need a function that will take at most X objects from that generator at once and save it using `batch_create`. This way, in a single moment we'll be holding no more than X objects in a memory.

```
from itertools import islice

def bulk_create_iter(iterable, batch_size=10000):
    """Bulk create supporting generators. Returns only count of created objects."""
    created = 0
    while True:
        objects = Model.bulk_create(islice(iterable, batch_size))
        created += len(objects)
        if not objects:
            break
    return created
```

and use it like this

```
print(bulk_create_iter(data_gen))
# prints 100000
```

The reason why can't just use `batch_create` is that internally it's doing `list(objs)`, so the whole generator is instantiated and saved to the memory. In this approach, we're instantiating maximum of `batch_size` objects at once. This method can be used to process even very large sets, as memory consumption should be constant (tested with 15 000 000 records, memory usage was under 300MB all the time).

Ready to use, generic version of this function, as a method of Django `Manager` class (you can use it in your model by writing `objects = BulkManager()`):

```
from itertools import islice
from django.db import models

class BulkManager(models.Manager):

    def bulk_create_iter(self, iterable, batch_size=10000):
        """Bulk create supporting generators, returns number of created objects."""
        created = 0
        while True:
            objects = self.bulk_create(islice(iterable, batch_size))
            created += len(objects)
            if not objects:
                break
        return created
```

Comment: I see that this code is based on  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create. But I think the while loop is infinite, as the islice() is always slicing the first xxx (10000) records in the iterable. It will always return the same records and do not progress through the iterable. I am relatively new to python and django, so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I faced with the same problem and ended up with this solution:

```
class BulkCreateManager(object):

    model = None
    chunk_size = None
    instances = None

    def __init__(self, model, chunk_size=None, *args):
        self.model = model
        self.chunk_size = chunk_size
        self.instances = []

    def append(self, instance):
        if self.chunk_size and len(self.instances) > self.chunk_size:
            self.create()
            self.instances = []

        self.instances.append(instance)

    def create(self):
        self.model.objects.bulk_create(self.instances)


instances = BulkCreateManager(Model, 23000)
for host in hosts:
    instance = ...
    instances.append(instance)

instances.create()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it'll be helpful for someone, this is an example of using generators + banch_size in Django:

```
from itertools import islice
from my_app.models import MyModel

def create_data(data):
    bulk_create(MyModel, generator())

def bulk_create(model, generator, batch_size=10000):
    """
    Uses islice to call bulk_create on batches of
    Model objects from a generator.
    """
    while True:
        items = list(islice(generator, batch_size))
        if not items:
            break
        model.objects.bulk_create(items)

def generator(data):
    for row in data:
        yield MyModel(field1=data['field1'])
```

The original article was here - https://concisecoder.io/2019/04/19/avoid-memory-issues-with-djangos-bulk_create/

Comment: The article: https://web.archive.org/web/20211223115647/https://concisecoder.io/2019/04/19/avoid-memory-issues-with-djangos-bulk_create/

Comment: Isn't   -->   items = list(islice(generator, batch_size))  <--  always going to return the same set of records and thus lead to an infinite while loop?

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share a slightly different approach which may help someone else.
The first thing to do to reduce memory dependency is NOT to load the entire dataset into memory. If the date comes from a file, just read a set batch size of records from the file, then create object list and write that to database.
Then clear that object list and create the next batch. This way not the entire dataset is loaded into memory at once.

In my case I had the entire data loaded into the memory (list) since it wasn't too large and I had to do something else with it. So I decided to extract a subset (batch) of the list and write it to database at a time.

```
# MyModelObjectList is the list variable with all the data model objects
# batch_size is the number of records you want to write to DB in one transaction
def my_bulk_create(MyModel, MyModelObjectList, batch_size=1000):
    for x in range(0, len(MyModelObjectList), batch_size):
        MyModel.objects.bulk_create(MyModelObjectList[ x: x+batch_size ]) # Extracting a subset of the list
```

You could have used islice() instead

```
def my_bulk_create(MyModel, MyModelObjectList, batch_size=1000):    
    for x in range(0, len(MyModelObjectList), batch_size):
        MyModel.objects.bulk_create(list(islice(MyModelObjectList, x, x+batch_size))
```

I guess this will remove the infinite loop from this [code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)

```
def my_bulk_create(MyModel, MyModelObjectList, batch_size=1000):    
    batchStart = 0
    while True:
        batch= list(islice(MyModelObjectList, batchStart, batchStart + batch_size))
        if not batch:
            break
        batchStart += batch_size # New start position for the next iteration
        MyModel.objects.bulk_create(batch)
```

**NB:** I have not personally executed the code snippets provided here, except the first one. So you may have to debug it a bit.